# Help in example for Covariance zero doesn't always imply independence

Tags: probability, covariance, independence

I have the following example for which I need help.

Suppose we first sample a real number **x** from a uniform distribution over the interval [−1, 1]. We next sample a random variable **s**. With probability 1/2, we choose the value of **s** to be 1. Otherwise, we choose the value of **s** to be −1. We can then generate a random variable **y** by assigning **y = sx**. Clearly, **x** and **y** are not independent, because **x** completely determines the magnitude of **y**. However, Cov(**x**, **y**) = 0.

Can someone show me full derivation of the covariance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align} Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X,SX) &= \mathbb{E} \left[X SX\right] - \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E} [SX] \\ & = \mathbb{E}[S] \mathbb{E} \left[X^2\right] - \mathbb{E} \left[X\right]\mathbb{E}[S]\mathbb{E}[X] \quad \text{(independence)} \\ & = 0 \times \mathbb{E} \left[X^2\right] - 0 \times 0 \times 0 \\ &= 0\end{align}

so you only need that for (measurable) functions of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, say $g$ and $f$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[g(X) f(Y)\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[g(X) \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ f(Y) \right] $$