# Covariance example in deep learning book

Tags: covariance, independence

Someone please help me understand this question. The question is already asked: [Help in example for Covariance zero doesn't always imply independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266370/help-in-example-for-covariance-zero-doesnt-always-imply-independence/326600#326600)

I understand $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$, but I still don't understand why $\mathbb{E}(S)=0$. We have $p(s)=\frac{1}{2}$ when sampling on $[-1, 1]$ and $p(s)=0$ when sampling out of $[-1,1]$. Then
 $$\mathbb{E}(S)=\int{Sp(S)dS}=p(S)\int{SdS}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\Big|_{-1}^1\right) = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $S$ in the question was defined to be $1$ with probability one half and $-1$ with probability one half. That gives us expected value equal to $0$.

$$
E[S]=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1)=0
$$

Your $S$ seems to be something else.